# Comparing a field value to a large list of potential values

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field

I'm looking for a way to compare the value of a field to a list of potential values (static, not from another field) and then put the result (True if it's on the list, False if it is not). The actual business problem is looking at a zip code on an Account to see if it is in a list of zip codes (about 100) where we're not able to operate, thus telling us that we can't do anything with this lead/account or are subject to some restrictions.

The obvious way of doing this would be with a formula but my formula skills are not up to the task - and it seems rather tedious to do an IF statement for this. Is there a way to do this with a formula that doesn't involve a lot of IFs? Is there a way to do this with a Trigger? I'd love to avoid an Apex solution if possible (our Apex developers are overworked and I don't want to get lost in a backlog).

Comment: This may no longer be relivant but using a CASE function would get this..

CASE(Zip__c,
10028, "yay",
10029, "yay",
10030, "nay",
"nay")